# How to optimize regex-based parsing of large log file?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, logfile

I have currently created the required function to parse a log file which is several hundred thousand lines long (possibly). Now the issue is that I search for Thread IDs 0..19 via double-for-loops like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for(int j = JAnalyzer.csvlog.size()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if(JUtility.hasThreadHung(JAnalyzer.csvlog.get(j), i)) {
            listOfHungThreads.add(JAnalyzer.csvlog.get(i));
            noThreadsHung++;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason being that I require to search the *entire* file for every thread ID. Thus my question would be whether there is a more effective way to handle such a procedure as I have never tackled a situation like this before.

The following is the `hasThreadHung` method.

```
public static boolean hasThreadHung(final String str, final int threadId) {     
    String pattern = "ScriptExecThread\\(" + Integer.toString(threadId) + "\\).*.starting.*.on";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    boolean hasHung = m.find();
    m.reset();
    return hasHung;
}
```

---

Please do not consider this premature optimization. The current way of handling this simply takes too long.

Comment: A more efficient way would be to search for any of the 20 thread ids in a single pass.  The overhead is likely to be mostly reading and parsing the log file and repeating this 20x will be very inefficient.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Could you please elaborate? In case I was a bit vague, the entire log file requires a pass for every thread ID (ranging from 0-19).

Comment: What is `JAnalyzer.csvlog`?

Comment: @HannoBinder A temporary `ArrayList` that I'm using.

Comment: Of course. But what's *inside* it? The lines of a log file (Strings)? Or mutliple full log files?

Comment: @HannoBinder - Just the lines of a single log file. I will be directly parsing the log file in the future.

Comment: And how is `JUtility.hasThreadHung` implemented. Can this be changed to search for multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: @HannoBinder - I shall append the JUtility.hasThreadHung. It may not be written perfectly but I wanted something that's easy to read and works. One moment.

Comment: Ok, this can be optimized. 1. don't re-compile the same pattern for every line, 2. use a single pattern for all threads, like `"ScriptExecThread\\([0-9]+\\)`. Then you only have to search each line *once*.

Comment: @HannoBinder - Hmm yes that does sound like a really good solution. I'll do that real quick.

Comment: @HannoBinder - Thanks, just what I needed. Works way faster now. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: Btw, `".*."` is usually represented as `".+"`.

Comment: @HannoBinder Oh thanks, I am quite new to REGEX as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose something like the following. It will search the given string for the hung-thread pattern and return the thread's number (as a string) if it is found, or `null` if no thread hung.

```
final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile( "ScriptExecThread\\(([0-9]+)\\).*.starting.*.on" );

public static String getHungThread(final String str ) {     
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(str);
    boolean hasHung = m.find();
    if ( hasHung ) {
      return m.group(1);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```